# Exception handling using Kafka rider in MassTransit

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

In MassTransit while using transport like RabbitMQ when an exception is thrown, the message goes into queue `queue_name_error`. But using Kafka, there is no topic with `_error` suffix, nor similar queue on supporting transport. How to handle exceptions properly using Kafka with MassTransit, and where erroneous messages can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Kafka (and Azure Event Hub) are essentially log files with a fancy API, there is no need for an _*error* queue, as there are no queues anyway. There are no dead letters either. So the built-in error handling of MassTransit that moves faulted messages to the _*error* doesn't apply (nor does it make sense).

You can use the retry middleware (UseMessageRetry, etc.) with topic endpoints, to handle transient exceptions. You can also log the offset of poison messages to deal with them. The offset doesn't change, the messages remain in the topic until the expiration is reached.

Comment: Hi Chris, I can log the offset, partition, topic of the fault message, but how can I have the raw data to check the exception then fix that bug?

Comment: You can read the raw data from Kafka at that topic, partition, and offset.