# Handling errors in MassTransit Kafka consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

I came across [this response from Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65521770/174929) regarding kafka exception handling in MT, and I was wondering - if I'd like to use Kafka DLQs for poison messages (as mentioned [here](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/dead-letter-queue.html) or suggested [there](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-for-apache-kafka-deep-dive-part-1-error-han) under Error Recovery), does it mean I will need to implement it on my own via the MT middleware (send to DLQ in an exception handling middleware)?